# Directorio por Default en Cmder

Tags: cmder

Actualmente estoy desarrollando un proyecto con Larabel 7 y uso Cmder, pero cada ves que uso Cmder abre la ruta por default.

¿Alguien sabe como hacer que la ruta por default sea la carpeta donde esta mi proyecto?
Me refiero que envés de tener que realizar una serie de comandos para llegar a la carpeta proyecto (como .. y cd), cuando se abra Cmder ya este configurado para iniciar en esa carpeta proyecto.

Ruta por default actual:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ruta por default deseada:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Opción 1:

Para cmder v1.3.6 o superior (a mayo de 2022):

- Ir a 'settings'
- En el grupo de configuración 'Startup', clic en 'Tasks'
- Seleccionar la consola que se desea modificar (p.ej. `cmd::Cmder`, `cmd::Cmder as Admin`, `bash::bash`, etc.)
- Clic en el botón que dice 'Startup dir...'
- Seleccione el directorio que desea fijar como punto de inicio para la consola seleccionada

### Opción 2:

También se puede buscar en `<USER_HOME>/cmder/vendor` el archivo `init.bat` y, antes de la línea

```
:: Set home path
```

poner la línea:

```
@cd /d "C:/xammp/htdocs/laravel/"
```

### Opción 3:

- Crear un link/atajo/shortcut a cmder. "cmder laravel"
- Editar las propiedades del link, cambiar el valor de "Iniciar en" y poner allí el directorio deseado
- Ejecutar el atajo.

### Opción 4:

Si eso no funciona, es necesario revisar el archivo `ConEmu.xml` en la instalacion de Cmder y reemplazar las ocurrencias del viejo directorio por el nuevo.

Traducción libre de [este hilo en SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1135129/how-to-change-default-path-in-cmder).

Comment: La primera opción me funciono, !!!Gracias¡¡¡, Tuve que eliminar la instrucción "*cmd /k ""%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat" "" y luego agregar la dirección de la carpeta con la que quería iniciar.